# gnome network manager: no internet, ping works, dig @8.8.8.8 works

Tags: gnome, opensuse

Running opensuse tumbleweed with 4.7.5-1-default kernel and gnome.

Network managed with gnome's `network-manager`. Network (wired and wireless) connect to my router.

- ping works also to external IPs
- dig works if I provide the dns ip (eg. `8.8.8.8`)
- `nmcli dev show | grep DNS` shows the right nameservers (which I set in
  the network managers interface): 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4,
- but dig without specification of the dns IP does not work
- `ping` etc. to internet names (e.g. google.com) does not work.

  Am completely lost by now. Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the nameservers setup in network manager. Check what is currently set in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: only: # Generated by NetworkManager.

Comment: Whelp, there is the issue - you have no defined nameservers. You _technically_ have internet connectivity - you just can not resolve any domains to IP addresses. Try poking around in network-manager and adding in your own nameservers, `8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`

Comment: Thank you, that is what I did. And I believe that is why "nmcli dev show | grep DNS" show the right nameservers. But they seem not to be used. To be sure, these ip are set in network-manager's interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Matt stated the solution in his comment but I failed to understand it.)
Solution found on opensuse forum: the /etc/resolve.conf file was corrupted (empty). After deleting it and rebooting, the system (network-manager?) generated a new, working version. It contains the ip of the nameserver.